# Rails url generation error on a form_for nested route and custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, url, routes

So I have two models a `booker` and a `booking_ticket`. I have nested the routes of `booking_ticket` under `booker`, but I also want to create a new `booking_ticket` without a `booker`, so I created a custom route. My action works properly when I try to create using the nested route but not on my custom path.

my routes.rb

```
resources :bookers do
 resources :booking_tickets
end
get '/booking_tickets/new', to: 'booking_tickets#new', as: 'new_booking_ticket'
```

This is the error I'm getting from rails when I use the custom path:

[image]

I don't understand where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom route for `create` action, your current custom resource is for `new` action:

```
post '/booking_tickets/create', to: 'booking_tickets#create'
```

Or, since you seem to be using defaults, just replace your current custom route with:

```
resources :booking_tickets, only: [:new, :create]
```

Be sure to add it **outside** `resources :bookers` block:

```
resources :bookers do
  resources :booking_tickets
end

resources :booking_tickets, only: [:new, :create]
```

Comment: Thank you! knew I was forgetting something